# ASP.NET Membership: Troca de Framework 3.5 para 4.5

Tags: asp.net, segurança, asp.net-membership

Alguém sabe me informar o que posso ter em danos do "Membership" se eu mudar meu framework de 3.5 para 4.5?

Eu tenho dúvida se meu sistema de login ficará intacto, ou seja, se não muda nada do controle de usuário que era feito antes.

Comment: Espero que você obtenha boas respostas (e a do Cigano já é excelente). Só queria comentar que mesmo com uma expectativa otimista com relação a mudança, é sempre bom experimentar em um ambiente de testes antes de fazer isso onde a mudança vai valer de verdade ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori, não. Não haverá impactos na troca de Framework, a não ser que você tenha feito uma implementação sua do Membership que use [uma dessas estruturas na implementação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd409230%28VS.100%29.aspx#base_class_libraries).

Em todo caso, a implementação pros Frameworks 3.5 e 4.5 do Membership é a mesma.

Comment: Cigano muito obrigado.